# Run vite preview with --profile

Tags: vite, react-devtools

I'm trying to run `vite preview` and use the react profiler in dev tools, but I can only get the profiler working if I run `vite --profile` which is a dev build, and I need production.

I've tried this suggestion: https://gist.github.com/bvaughn/25e6233aeb1b4f0cdb8d8366e54a3977?permalink_comment_id=4192069#gistcomment-4192069 but no luck.

I run `vite build` which generates a production build, but my issue is that the profile is never enabled (i.e. not included in the production build). I've tried running `vite build --profile` but no luck either.

The docs are pretty light on this issue as far as I can tell.

Comment: What was the issue you encountered when trying the suggestion you linked? Could you provide some output as to what happened, did the app build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliasing `react-dom/client` (for SPAs) to `react-dom/profiling` at build time should do the trick:

```
// vite.config.ts
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

const profiling = isProduction && {
  "react-dom/client": "react-dom/profiling",
};

export default defineConfig({
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...profiling,
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For easier debug you can add `esbuild.minifyIdentifiers` property and set it to `false`, that will keep not minified component names.

```
// vite.config.ts
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

const profiling = isProduction && {
  "react-dom/client": "react-dom/profiling",
};

export default defineConfig({
  esbuild: {
    minifyIdentifiers: false 
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...profiling,
    },
  },
});
```